# How to conditionally combine two numpy arrays of the same shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This sounds simple, and I think I'm overcomplicating this in my mind.

I want to make an array whose elements are generated from two source arrays of the same shape, depending on which element in the source arrays is greater.

to illustrate:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array((2,3,0))
array2 = np.array((1,5,0))

array3 = (insert magic)
>> array([2, 5, 0))
```

I can't work out how to produce an array3 that combines the elements of array1 and array2 to produce an array where only the greater of the two array1/array2 element values is taken.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We could use NumPy built-in [`np.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html), made exactly for that purpose -

```
np.maximum(array1, array2)
```

Another way would be to use the NumPy ufunc [`np.max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax) on a `2D` stacked array and `max-reduce` along the first axis `(axis=0)` -

```
np.max([array1,array2],axis=0)
```

Timings on 1 million datasets -

```
In [271]: array1 = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000000))

In [272]: array2 = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000000))

In [274]: %timeit np.maximum(array1, array2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 ms per loop

In [275]: %timeit np.max([array1, array2],axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.31 ms per loop

# @Eric Duminil's soln1
In [276]: %timeit np.where( array1 > array2, array1, array2)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.15 ms per loop

# @Eric Duminil's soln2
In [277]: magic = lambda x,y : np.where(x > y , x, y)

In [278]: %timeit magic(array1, array2)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.13 ms per loop
```

---

**Extending to other supporting ufuncs**

Similarly, there's `np.minimum` for finding element-wise minimum values between two arrays of same or broadcastable shapes. So, to find element-wise minimum between `array1` and `array2`, we would have :

```
np.minimum(array1, array2)
```

For a complete list of `ufuncs` that support this feature, please refer to the [**`docs`**](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/ufuncs.html) and look for the keyword : `element-wise`. `Grep`-ing for those, I got the following ufuncs :

> add, subtract, multiply, divide, logaddexp, logaddexp2, true_divide,
>   floor_divide, power, remainder, mod, fmod, divmod, heaviside, gcd,
>   lcm, arctan2, hypot, bitwise_and, bitwise_or, bitwise_xor, left_shift,
>   right_shift, greater, greater_equal, less, less_equal, not_equal,
>   equal, logical_and, logical_or, logical_xor, maximum, minimum, fmax,
>   fmin, copysign, nextafter, ldexp, fmod

Comment: Ahah. Thanks for the `timeit`, but it's pretty clear that the standard, optimized numpy way is faster than a custom one. My method would only make sense with a more complex condition.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yup totally! Just trying to see how various methods stack up, for myself and others as well.

Answer (score 17):

If your condition ever becomes more complex, you could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array((2,3,0))
array2 = np.array((1,5,0))
array3 = np.where( array1 > array2, array1, array2)
# array([2, 5, 0])
```

You could replace `array1 > array2` with any condition. If all you want is the maximum, go with @Divakar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558114/how-to-conditionally-combine-two-numpy-arrays-of-the-same-shape/46558133#46558133).

And just for fun :

```
magic = lambda x,y : np.where(x > y , x, y)
magic(array1, array2)
# array([2, 5, 0])
```