# Maximum between an array and a number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

When using:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,-3,-1, 0,3,-1])
print [max(A[j], 0) for j in range(len(A))]
```

we get `[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]`, as desired.

**How to get the same directly with a numpy function, such as [`np.max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html)?**

```
print max(A, 0)  # ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
print np.max(A, 0)  # 3
print np.max(A, 0, axis=0)  # argument axis not working
print np.amax(A, 0)  # 3
```

Comment: .. `np.maximum`?

Comment: If you are just getting the max between `A` and `0` (like for a relu) then you can just do `A*(A>0)`

Comment: @Divakar Oh that's right!  I always thought np.max is an alias for np.maximum because I could not find any doc for np.max... This link does not work: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.max.html

Comment: @Divakar please pardon me, but I think the question here is about the non-existence of doc for np.max / confusion between np.max and np.maximum, more than about "conditionally combine two numpy arrays of the same shape". My title states that it's the contrary: conditionally compare an array and *a number* (obviously not same shape).

Comment: @Basj Well `np.maximum` as stated in the linked dup Q&A works on all broadcastable shapes and not necessarily the same shapes and as such works here as well. The question I read here was - `How to get the same directly with a numpy function, such as np.max?` and `np.maximum` works perfectly as again stated there.

Comment: @Basj It was stated clearly in the accepted solution - `Similarly, there's np.minimum for finding element-wise minimum values between two arrays of same or broadcastable shapes.`.

Comment: Yes @Divakar but both the question and the main part of the answer states it's the contrary of what I'm asking here ;) I'm asking about `np.??max(array, single-number)` and this linked question is about: `We could use NumPy built-in np.maximum, made exactly for that purpose - np.maximum(array1, array2)`, so it's like "two different problems having the same solution (using np.maximum)" but not "the same question".

Comment: @Basj You are asking about : `np.??max(array, single-number)` and `np.maximum(array1, array2)` is the solution. I am not sure where exactly are we having the confusion?

Comment: @Basj The term `broadcastable` solves it for you. We can't be having n-number of questions on Stackoverflow corresponding to `Maximum between a 1D array and a number`, `Maximum between a 2D array and a number` and so on, all of which would have the exact same solution. Stackoverflow would be swamped that way.

Comment: @Divakar Just two questions are needed: `Maximum between (n-dim) array and (n-dim) array` (this covers np.maximum(A, B) with A **and** B  1D or 2D or 1000D ;))  and `Maximum between (n-dim) array and a single number`. This question here is the latter. It's two different things though.

Comment: @Basj Well then there are arrays with different number of dims like (2,3,4) against (3,4) that are broadcastable against each other. So, again you would have : `Maximum between (n dim) array and (n-1 dim)` and `Maximum between (n dim) array and (n-2 dim)` and so on. Again infinite number of questions on SO to flood it with. The term `broadcastable` as stated in the accepted solution to linked dup is the key term as it covers all of the scenarios including the ones stated at the start of this comment, your question (this is doing broadcasting too) and the linked Q&A.

Comment: You're surely right @Divakar, but if I arrived on this question from Google: [How to conditionally combine two numpy arrays *of the same shape*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558114/how-to-conditionally-combine-two-numpy-arrays-of-the-same-shape) I would have thought that it's not related to this problem (not knowing broadcasting)... Never mind, thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `np.maximum(A, 0)`. Contrary to `np.max` function, it accepts *two* arguments, and compares them element-wise. In your case, since the second argument is a scalar value, the comparison will happen by *broadcasting* it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I always thought `np.max` is an alias for `np.maximum`!

Comment: @Basj: it's not. it seems to be an alias for `np.amax` (though the docs do no state that clearly)